# Play war deployment prevents Tomcat from stopping

Tags: scala, tomcat, playframework, akka, playframework-2.2

I am currently experiencing some onStop issues with my play application under Tomcat.
I am using play 2.2.2, sbt 0.13.0, scala 2.10.4 and Tomcat 7 and jdk1.6.

To create a war file I am using the play2war plugin(1.2) with:

```
Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "2.5"
```

So deploying and running the application as well as Tomcat itself is running without any issues. But as soon as I try to stop the server with the default shutdown.sh I get

```
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] appears to have started a thread named [play-scheduler-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] appears to have started a thread named [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] appears to have started a thread named [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] appears to have started a thread named [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@384e9bea]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@4e57dc21]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1@4679cf8c]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom@67291479]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@384e9bea]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@39ff48d8]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@384e9bea]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@27077aa7]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [akka.actor.ActorCell$$anon$1] (value [akka.actor.ActorCell$$anon$1@5c057df5]) and a value of type [scala.collection.immutable.Nil$] (value [List()]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@384e9bea]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@6c908f05]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Aug 21, 2014 6:15:18 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/WEBSERVICE] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1@4679cf8c]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom@69dc8f2]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
```

After that the application and tomcat are down but I still see the tomcat prozess zombieing through

```
ps -ef
```

The only possibility to kill it completly is by `kill -9 <pid>`.
So I started searching through the web an stumbled upon similar problems suggesting to perform the `.shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` on the actor system that is used.

So I created a Global object with overriding the onStop method:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
 val actorSystem = Application.system

 override def onStop(app: Application) {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(4 seconds)

    Logger.info("Shutting down Actorsystem")

    Akka.system.shutdown()
    Akka.system.awaitTermination(timeout.duration)
    actorSystem.shutdown()
    actorSystem.awaitTermination(timeout.duration)
  }

}
```

But it won't solve the issue. I tried to shutdown my own ActorSystem as well as the default play actorsystem through `Akka.system` but it has no effect.
The onStop method gets execute as I see the Log statements in catalina.out.

So to nail down the problem I set up a completly new play 2.3.3 with just a simple string response. Without a actor system besides the play default one and integrated the play2war plugin to see if the problems are caused by my code or by play itself. And the issue was the same.

So I am locking for some advice how it could be possible to shutdown these scheduler and dispatchers and so on that are spawned by play but not killed on shutdown?

I really would appreciate any help!

**Edit:**

I also tried the solution provided in [Oracle driver memory leak - Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754858) by removing the oracle driver in my application lib - but without any change in the tomcat behaviour

There are also multiple Topics within Play2war Github based on this topic but unfortunatly there are no solutions:

[Leak error and Tomcat is never shutdown #108](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/issues/108)

[tomcat 6: hangs on shutdown #161](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/issues/161)

Comment: Not an answer, but in my experience it's very hard to be sure tomcat really stops. My advice is to run tomcat as a service. Besides other advantages, it will always make sure tomcat is stopped when shutting down the service.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatly I don`t have the possibility to run it as a service. Besides that I don`t really get the meaning of: "hard to be sure tomcat really stops". Because either the process is ended and the port is not longer occupied or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found a solution for this problem in this thread:
[is-there-any-light-weight-actors-in-akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119349/is-there-any-light-weight-actors-in-akka/18120532#18120532)

As described by [Roland Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958431/roland-kuhn) it is possible to set the threads by akka to be daemon, which in the end won`t keep the VM from shutting down.

To do that just set in application.conf:

```
play.akka.daemonic=on
```

or which should also work:

```
akka {
  daemonic=on
}
```

With that the tomcat will shutdown without problems.

Comment: I have been troubleshooting some memory issues with my play2war-deployed Play 2 app recently and a colleague who's working on a similar project recommended this config. Since we started using it, we haven't been able to reproduce the memory leak in our QA environment & hopefully we'll see the same improvement in prod!